# Book for understanding latest Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to understand the Linux kernel. For this I have the book "UnderStanding the Linux Kernel, 3e". Inside the book I have found that the book has written based on Linux kernel 2.6. But as my knowledge the latest release is 4.1. If I follow this, can I understand the Linux kernel by reading this book? If not what is your suggestion?

After searching net found that most of the books are written on kernel 2.6.